# Setting up ignite context in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ignite

How to set up ignite context in spark using python .

```
igniteContext = IgniteContext(sparkContext,"c:/desktop/config.xml")
```

> Import Error : cannot import IgniteContext

Answer (score 2):

There is only Java and Scala API available for `IgniteRDD`.

Comment: Can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42061729/ignite-for-spark  @Valentin Kulichenko

Comment: Is there any work being done in order to create a Python API?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas Not what I'm aware of. What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to be able to access RDD/Datasets from both a python and spark context.  Data Science prefers python, Engineering prefers Scala and no one wants to budge.  Do you have any idea how much effort extending Ignite to support this would be?

Comment: I suggest you to go to Apache Ignite developers list with this question. You should be able to get better feedback regarding this there.

Comment: Done! http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com/Ignite-RDD-for-Python-td23545.html  Sorry for the delay, I must have completely missed the notification of you responding to me.