# Ignite for Spark

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I am trying to load ignite cache into spark . But I am getting java.sql.SQLException : Unsupported type 1111

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL data sources example")
                .config("spark.master", "spark://10.104.146.199:7077")
                .getOrCreate();

     Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:ignite:cfg://cache=DEVICE_CACHE:distributedJoins=false@file:///C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/ignite-client-config-with-timeout.xml") 
    .option("driver", "org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcDriver") 
    .option("dbtable", "DEVICE")
    .load();
     df.count();
```

Comment: You should look for the Spark Shared RDD which can be used to load an ignite cache as Spark RDD or Dataframe. https://ignite.apache.org/features/igniterdd.html

Comment: Is there any mapping issue in the above code? @ Manish Mishra

Comment: Please provide logs from the client and the Ignite server node.